# How to BREAK a While loop - Getting error: Syntax error: missing 'colon'

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to break a while loop in my SQL stored procedure, but I'm getting the error "Syntax error: missing 'colon' ".

![Error message]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QL02.jpg

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE COUNTER INT;
    DECLARE myvar INT;
    SET COUNTER = 0;
    SET myvar = 0;

    WHILE COUNTER < 5 DO

        IF myvar > 1 THEN
            INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (1);
        ELSE
            BREAK; /* Here I get Syntax error: missing 'colon' */
        END IF;

        SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1;

    END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: Research MySQL's keyword `DELIMITER` See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

Comment: Thank you @Madhur Bhaiya. It seems that it is a duplicate, I didn't find that question when I was researching.